# conditional probability question - Sanjay the kindergartener with chicken pox

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose the following facts to be true:

-- The probability of a random kindergartener having chicken pox at any given time is 2%.

-- Among kindergarteners who have chicken pox, 75% have red spots.

-- Among kindergarteners who do not have chicken pox, 1% have red spots.

Given that Sanjay, a kindergartener, has red spots, what is the probability that Sanjay has chicken pox?

This is my reasoning:

We know for sure that Sanjay has red spots. 75% of children who have chicken pox have red spots. That means 25% of children who have chicken pox DO NOT have red spots. The probability of Sanjay having chicken pox is 2%. Would it be 75% of 2%? I'm not very sure. This question is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard conditional probability question. By definition:

$$ P(\text{chicken pox} \mid \text{spots}) = \frac{P(\text{chicken pox} \cap \text{spots})}{P(\text{spots})} $$

So we now have to find two probabilities:

1. probability of a random person having chicken pox and spots
2. probability of a random person having spots

The first probability is given in the question, $2\%$ of people have chicken pox and of those, $75\%$ have red spots.

The second probability is marginally more difficult. $2\%$ of people have chicken pox and $75\%$ of those have red spots. We must also consider that $100\% - 2\%=98\%$ of people do not have chicken pox, and $1\%$ of those have red spots. Note that these events $\text{chicken pox} \cap \text{spots}$ and $\text{no chicken pox} \cap \text{spots}$ are disjoint (mutually exclusive) and therefore the probability of either happening is simply the sum of their probabilities.

Comment: So if I am understanding this correctly: for the first probability, we have to find 2% of 75%, giving us 1.50%. For the second probability, to find the probability of ALL people with spots, we have to add the probabilities of (those with spots and chicken pox) and (those with spots with NO chicken pox). 2% of 75% again is 1.50%. 1% of 98% is 0.98%. Add those two up and you get 2.48%. Would it be 1.5%/2.48%? I am supposed to present the answer as a fraction in simplest terms.

Comment: @MathyPerson, yes, that would be the answer. The simplest form should be $75/124$.

Answer (score 1):

Formally, you can apply Bayes's Theorem.

Informally, notice that $1.5$% of kindergartners have chicken pox *and* have red spots, 
while $0.98$% ($1$% of the other $98$%)have red spots but do not have chicken pox.
That is, out of $10000$ kindergartners, you would on average find
$248$ with red spots, of which $150$ had chicken pox and $98$ did not.

We know Sanjay is among the $248$, and must estimate the probability that he
is in the first subset of those children.

Comment: Would the probability then be 150/248 = 75/124? 150/248 looks similar to what I answered above to George V. Williams's answer.

Comment: As a fraction in lowest terms, I get the same answer as you.